# snowflake syntax error using procedure merge with language sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

I am trying to use merge statement in snowflake with language sql. Below is the layout of code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "USP_TEST"("FILE_DATE_TIME" VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE SQL
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$
DECLARE
   SRC_ID varchar(10000);
BEGIN

    SRC_ID:= <Some Select query>;
   
    merge into table a
    using ()b on <some join conditions>
    when matched then update
      <x no of statements>
    when not matched then insert
      <x no of statements> ;
    RETURN 'SUCCESS'
END;
$$
```

Error: syntax error line 8 at position 7 unexpected 'into'. syntax error line 8 at position 15 unexpected '.'.

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

The missing () for the select statement in SRC_ID: is the cause for this issue. The correct SP definition is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "USP_TEST"("FILE_DATE_TIME" VARCHAR(1000))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    EXECUTE AS CALLER
    AS 
    $$
    DECLARE
       SRC_ID varchar(10000);
    BEGIN
    
        SRC_ID:= (<Some Select query>);
       
        merge into <table>
        using ()b on <some join conditions>
        when matched then update
          <x no of statements>
        when not matched then insert
          <x no of statements> ;
        RETURN 'SUCCESS';
    END;
    $$
```

As an example here is the working SP definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "USP_TEST"("FILE_DATE_TIME" VARCHAR(1000))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    EXECUTE AS CALLER
    AS 
    $$
    DECLARE
       SRC_ID varchar(10000);
    BEGIN
    
        SRC_ID:= (select * from numtest);
    merge into target a using (select col1,col2 from ddm_tag group by col1) as b on target.col1 = b.col1
  when matched then update set target.col2 = b.col2
  when not matched then insert (col1, col2) values (b.col2, b.col2);
        RETURN 'SUCCESS';
    END;
    $$
```

Comment: I have added even then I get same error :(

Comment: It worked I was using double single quotes '' '' . Double single quotes is required only when we select Java Script as Language

Comment: Glad to know you got it working. But, the original question seems was not with those quotes.